# Mocking Service, Injecting repository & mapper. Integration Tests in Spring

Tags: java, mockito, mapstruct

I'm trying to mock Service, which is responsible for getting Entities from Repository and Mapping them to Pojo. I'm getting an error and I don't understand why it works this way.
Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Error:

```
class com.example.demo.businessLogic.person.Person cannot be cast to class 
com.example.demo.postgres.entity.PersonEntity (com.example.demo.businessLogic.person.Person and 
com.example.demo.postgres.entity.PersonEntity are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.demo.businessLogic.person.Person cannot be cast to 
class com.example.demo.postgres.entity.PersonEntity (com.example.demo.businessLogic.person.Person
 and com.example.demo.postgres.entity.PersonEntity are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

personService.getAllPerson() returns Pojo:

```
@Override
public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
    return personRepoPostgres.findAll().stream()
            .map(personMapper::entityToPerson)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class cTest {

    @Mock
    PersonRepoPostgres personRepoPostgres;

    @Mock
    PersonMapper personMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    PersonService personService;

    @Test
    void test(){
        Mockito.when(personService.getAllPerson()).thenReturn(List.of(new Person("Zamor")));
        List<Person> personArrayList = personService.getAllPerson();

        Assertions.assertEquals(personArrayList.get(0), "Zamor");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to mock the method under test, when you should only mock dependencies of the method under test. `Mockito.when` should be used on methods in the `PersonRepoPostgress` class or the `PersonMapper` class, not `PersonService`.

There is no mock implementation for `PersonMapper`, so when `personMapper::entityToPerson` is called it the default implementation is probably trying to cast `PersonEntity` to `Person`.

Switching your mocks to something like this should help:

```java
Mockito.when(personRepoPostgress.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of(new PersonEntity()));
Mockito.when(personMapper.entityToPerson(any(PersonEntity.class))).thenReturn(new Person("Zamor"));
```